# How does automatic weapon fire interact with the scatter property?

Tags: warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-1e

I am confused how to determine hits from a combat shotgun in Dark Heresy.  How does the scatter property interact with an auto-fire action when attacking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's confusing but they answered it in the Errata:**

> The Actions section starting on page 190 should  include a special
>   note concerning combining semi-auto and  full-auto ﬁre with the
>   Scatter quality, which reads “When  ﬁring a semi- or full-auto burst
>   at point blank range with a  weapon that has the Scatter quality, the
>   extra hits for rate of  ﬁre and scatter are worked out separately and
>   both applied.  For example, Horatius Kane ﬁres his combat shotgun at 
>   Heretic X. Kane is at point-blank range and ﬁres a semiautomatic
>   burst. Kane rolls 01 with his modiﬁed Ballistic  Skill of 70 (30 BS,
>   +30 for point-blank range, +10 for  ﬁring semi-auto) and hits by an amazing six degrees of  success. He gets one hit at 70, one hit for
>   semi-automatic  at 50, and a third hit for semi-auto at 30 (he does
>   not get a  fourth hit at 10, because the combat shotgun’s rate of ﬁre
>   is 3). He would get additional hits for scatter at 50, 30 and  10, for
>   a total of 6 hits on Heretic X, most likely shredding the cultist to
>   bits in the Emperor’s name.”

http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/dark-heresy/pdf/darkheresy-errata-v3.0-printable.pdf

Comment: I've found it much simpler and more satisfying to simply use 1 hit per level of success, rather than 2 hits per 2 levels.